# Filtering within summarise() in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm working on recreating the "Youngest Male Names" graphic from Five-Thirty-Eight: https://espnfivethirtyeight.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/silver-feature-youngest-men-names3.png?w=575&quality=90&strip=info

Currently I"m working on wrangling the data before getting it ready to plot. I start by filtering the data by gender for just males and then group the data by name. However, I need to also filter the results by `est_num_alive > 100,000` I can't figure out where to include this filter function in order to get the data correct.

```
young_male <- BabynamesDist %>%
  filter(sex == "M") %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(
    N = n(), est_num_alive = sum(est_alive_today),
    q1_age = wtd.quantile(age_today, est_alive_today, probs = 0.25),
    median_age = wtd.quantile(age_today, est_alive_today, probs = 0.5),
    q3_age = wtd.quantile(age_today, est_alive_today, probs = 0.75)) %>%

  arrange(desc(-median_age)) %>%

  head(25)
```

Right now, this code returns a group of names that all have only 1 person alive today with that name and who all have a median age of 4. Ex: Aadhavan with a median age of 4 and only 1 alive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
young_male <- BabynamesDist %>%
  filter(sex == "M") %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(est_num_alive = sum(est_alive_today)) %>%
  filter(est_num_alive > 100000) %>%
  summarise(
    N = n(), 
    q1_age = wtd.quantile(age_today, est_alive_today, probs = 0.25),
    median_age = wtd.quantile(age_today, est_alive_today, probs = 0.5),
    q3_age = wtd.quantile(age_today, est_alive_today, probs = 0.75)
  ) %>%
  arrange(desc(-median_age))
```

I think this is what you are going for, inferring information about the dataframe as best as I can. Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah this works! I'm still pretty new at r and didn't think about using the mutate function here. I was just trying to do the summation outside of a function. Thanks, I appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem! Welcome to R! Also, make sure to ```ungroup()``` when you want a mutation to happen across all groups and not within groups later with the same dataframe.